# Tell ListView adapter not to update on data change

Tags: android, list, listview

I am using a LinearLayout in a ScrollView. I fill that with a collection of objects, and when user clicks on one of them, it loads another activity with the same list of another objects. Those objects are in Application and i clear them whenever i want to get a new set of objects.
But now I wanted to replace ScrollView with ListView. I writed my own adapter for list....but when user clicks on one item, I clear that set and start another activity...but the previous ListView gets updated.

Can I somehow tell the list not to get updated, when data changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass to the adapter a copy of the list of objects.. and that way it wont change. it is not very efficient but yoy didnt give enough information for us to understand what are you trying to do

Comment: So...I am having an ArrayList in Application. Everytime I go to webservice/database I clear that ArrayList in fill it with new items. In Activity I then iterate through items and put them into LinearLayout with ScrollView. But when I want to use ListView, previous ListView gets updated (because I the same ArrayList for all Activities). Is it good idea to copy the values and make each ListView has its own copy of ArrayList? Or can I just somehow say to the list adapter not to update on data change?

Comment: i dont think you can tell that to the list and it doesnt make sence to be able to do that.. when the list loads, it takes it value from the ArrayList and that why you see the most updated values. for my understanding a copy is the way of doing it